# How can i read a Russian file in Java?

Tags: java, file, unicode

I tried adding UTF-8 for this but it didn't work out. What should i do for reading a Russian file in Java?

```
      FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream("russian.txt");
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream1);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8"));
```

Comment: What's the encoding of the Russian file?

Comment: Agree to Marko, probably it's the file's problem, not your application's.

Comment: okey i changed  the format of file to UTF-8. Now it reads "???????"

Comment: Can you open this file in your word editor (like openoffice or M$ word) and able to read? If not try installing the specific font and retry.

Comment: And what font are you using to display Russian Cyrillic? Instead of printing the contents, write them into a file and open in an editor that can handle cyrillic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the file is from Windows PC, try either "windows-1251" or "Cp1251" for the charset name.

If the file is somehow in the MS-DOS encoding, try using "Cp866".

Both of these are single-byte encodings and changing the file type to UTF-8 (which is multibyte) does nothing.

If all else fails, use the hex editor and dump a few hex lines of these file to you question. Then we'll detect the encoding.

Comment: i use android which also use java but when i try to read one file with Russian name from FileinputStream then it gave filenot found exception but that file present in sdcard what should i do

Answer (score 3):

As others mentioned you need to know how the file is encoded. A simple check is to (ab)use Firefox as an encoding detector: [answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3520401/1472628)

If this is a display problem, it depends what you mean by "reads": in the console, in some window? See also [How can I make a String with cyrillic characters display correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929573/how-can-i-make-a-string-with-cyrillic-characters-display-correctly)