# Read russian symbols from file in Java and output to console

Tags: java, encoding, readline, filewriter

I'm writing a small Java appliction. It just reads a text file and outputs its contnent to console. I do it using FileWriter, method readLine().
The file contains text in Russian. When I see console output - there are very strange symbols like there is something with encoding. What should I do in this situation?

thank you

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340042/how-can-i-read-a-russian-file-in-java

Comment: Can you describe how exactly you read the file, and how you write it to the console? And how do you view your console (in your IDE, or in a terminal window, ...)

Comment: Thank you for hint. I set env variable JAVA_OPTS_TOOL to windows-1251 and it worked.