# Reading .properties files written in russian

Tags: java, utf-8

I am trying to read in .properties files with many different languages, add new entries to them, sort, and print back to file. I have the encoding as UTF-8, and it works for all my current languages except Russian. When reading the file in I get all question marks from the Russian file. When it prints back out it has a lot of the correct text, but has random question marks here and there. Here is my code for reading in the file.

```
Properties translation = new Properties() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public synchronized Enumeration<Object> keys() {
        return Collections.enumeration(new TreeSet<Object>(super.keySet()));
    }
}

byte[] readIn = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
String replacer = new String(readIn).replace("\\","\\\\");
translation.load(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(replacer.getBytes()),"UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new String(readIn)` and `replacer.getBytes()` don't use UTF8. They use your platform default encoding. Pass `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` as an additional argument to both calls.

BTW, transforming a STring to a byte array, to then transform back the bytes to characters and reading them is a waste of time and resources. Just do

```
translation.load(new StringReader(replacer));
```

Comment: This looks like it fixed it when printing back to the file. Though it still does display the question marks if printed to system.out rather than back into the file. Odd.

Comment: Your console, or its font, is probably unable to display russian characters.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes changing the encoding to utf-8 gives rise to errors, such as some extra characters or does nothing.
The link: [How can i read a Russian file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340042/how-can-i-read-a-russian-file-in-java) may help you.